# replace String with another in java

Tags: java, string

What function can replace a string with another string?

Example #1: What will replace `"HelloBrother"` with `"Brother"`?

Example #2: What will replace `"JAVAISBEST"` with `"BEST"`?

Comment: So you want only the last word?

Answer (score 155):

The [`replace`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method is what you're looking for.

For example:

```
String replacedString = someString.replace("HelloBrother", "Brother");
```

Answer (score 49):

**Try this:**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29

```
String a = "HelloBrother How are you!";
String r = a.replace("HelloBrother","Brother");

System.out.println(r);
```

**This would print out "Brother How are you!"**

Comment: Almost -1 for giving out a link to an ancient copy of the javadocs.

Answer (score 11):

There is a possibility not to use extra variables

```
String s = "HelloSuresh";
s = s.replace("Hello","");
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: It's hardly a new answer, but an improvement of @DeadProgrammer's answer.

Comment: This is existing answer please try with different approach @oleg sh

Answer (score 8):

Replacing one string with another can be done in the below methods

**Method 1:**  Using String `replaceAll`

```
 String myInput = "HelloBrother";
 String myOutput = myInput.replaceAll("HelloBrother", "Brother"); // Replace hellobrother with brother
 ---OR---
 String myOutput = myInput.replaceAll("Hello", ""); // Replace hello with empty
 System.out.println("My Output is : " +myOutput);
```

**Method 2**: Using `Pattern.compile`

```
 import java.util.regex.Pattern;
 String myInput = "JAVAISBEST";
 String myOutputWithRegEX = Pattern.compile("JAVAISBEST").matcher(myInput).replaceAll("BEST");
 ---OR -----
 String myOutputWithRegEX = Pattern.compile("JAVAIS").matcher(myInput).replaceAll("");
 System.out.println("My Output is : " +myOutputWithRegEX);
```

**Method 3**: Using `Apache Commons` as defined in the link below:

```
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-z.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replace(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```

**[REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25258335/3492139)**

Answer (score 6):

```
     String s1 = "HelloSuresh";
     String m = s1.replace("Hello","");
     System.out.println(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion,
Let's say you have two same words in the String

```
String s1 = "who is my brother, who is your brother"; // I don't mind the meaning of the sentence.
```

replace function will change every string is given in the first parameter to the second parameter

```
System.out.println(s1.replace("brother", "sister")); // who is my sister, who is your sister
```

and you can use also replaceAll method for the same result

```
System.out.println(s1.replace("brother", "sister")); // who is my sister, who is your sister
```

if you want to change just the first string which is positioned earlier,

```
System.out.println(s1.replaceFirst("brother", "sister")); // whos is my sister, who is your brother.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method to achieve this:

```
String outputString1 = inputString.replace("HelloBrother", "Brother");
String outputString2 = inputString.replace("JAVAISBEST", "BEST");
```