# Android replace double quotes with one quote

Tags: java, android, string, replace

The string output is `"data", "data1", "data2", "data3"`

i want it to replace `"` with `'` so the string output will be `'data', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3'`

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

use **[String class replaceAll method](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)**

**Syntax:** `public String replaceAll (String regularExpression, String replacement)`

In your case

```
String str = "data", "data1", "data2", "data3";
str = str.replaceAll("\"", "'");
System.out.println(str);
```

Then you will get output as

```
'data','data1','data2','data3'
```

From Android API, `replaceAll` says

> **Matches for regularExpression within this string with the given replacement.**
>
> **If the same regular expression is to be used for multiple operations, it may be more efficient to reuse a compiled Pattern.**

Answer (score 2):

simply use String class to make this happen like:

```
String s = "data";
        String replace = s.replace( "\"",  "'");
        System.out.println(replace);
```

Answer (score 1):

---

**Method 1:**  Using String `replaceALL`

```
 String myInput = "\"data1\",\"data2\",\"data3\",\"data4\",\"data5\"";
 String myOutput = myInput.replaceAll("\"", "'");
 System.out.println("My Output with Single Quotes is : " +myOutput);
```

**Output:**

```
My Output with Single Quotes is : 'data1','data2','data3','data4','data5'
```

---

**Method 2**: Using `Pattern.compile`

```
 import java.util.regex.Pattern;
 String myInput = "\"data1\",\"data2\",\"data3\",\"data4\",\"data5\"";
 String myOutputWithRegEX = Pattern.compile("\"").matcher(myInput).replaceAll("'");
 System.out.println("My Output with Single Quotes is : " +myOutputWithRegEX);
```

---

**Method 3**: Using `Apache Commons` as defined in the link below:

```
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-z.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replace(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```

---