# How to change one character to string in string variable

Tags: java, string

I have string "2x+3" and I want change 'x' to string "8".

```
String operation = "2x+3";
String x = "8";
```

And I want result such as "2*8+3"

or

```
String operation = "x+3";
String x = "8";
```

And I want result such as "8+3"

Does anyone know how to solve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
operation = operation.replace("x","8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't change the same string, because strings are immutable objects in java. What you can do is use the replace function in string class and get a new string out of it.

Have a look at this question : [replace String with another in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216272/replace-string-with-another-in-java)