# Remove specific words or letters from a String

Tags: java

May i ask, how do i remove words and letters from a string?

Example: is, are
Example: -ing.

A sentence:  A wolf is eating a sheep.

becomes: A wolf eat a sheep.

Thanks!

Comment: Refer this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216272/replace-string-with-another-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method

```
String str = "A wolf is eating a sheep.";

str = str.replace("ing","");
```

or

```
str = str.replace("eating","eat");
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible not to specify the string in the first place and let the removal take place by itself?

Comment: How will the code know what you want to remove ? You will have to specify the removable or replaceable string in the first place!!