# Remove letter from AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I use a `AutoCompleteTextView` for `login form`. But i want remove a `character` if he is here.

**Exemple :** User login is : 784589. But if we write !784589, we delete "!" character.

It's possible ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216272/replace-string-with-another-in-java

Comment: I don't know really what is the function who i need to use. I just want remove a character from AutoCompletetextView. Or detect if we have this character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution  :

```
 AutoCompleteTextView textView5 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.userName);

        if (textView5.getText().toString().contains("#")) {
            textView5.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.connect_error));
        }
        else{
            (...)
        }
```