# Java deleteCharAt with ++ or --

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder phoneNumber = new StringBuilder("828-707-5634");
    for(int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.length(); i++)
    {
      if (phoneNumber.charAt(i) == '-')
        phoneNumber.deleteCharAt(i--);
    }

    System.out.print(phoneNumber);
}
```

Indeed this removes the dash from the phone number, but intuitively I would have expected it to remove the character just before the dash (because of the --). How/why does this work? Additionally, I find that if I use ++ or omit the increment/decrement entirely the dashes are still removed.

Comment: you are changing the object during inspecting its content in the for loop....

Comment: `i--` feeds the unchanged `i` to the method and afterwards decrements the value. It is the same as if you would call `deleteCharAt(i); i--;`. The `--i` operator does decrement it before feeding the method.

Comment: If you want it to delete de character before the dash, use ```--i```

Comment: stop using inline postfix and infix operations.

Comment: To be fair, this is a "correct" solution to decrement the index since you update the  String directly. But I prefer to simply read from the end, that way I don't have to bother with the new length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deleteCharAt` receives the *unincremented* value of `i`, since the value of the *expression* `i--` is the unincremented value. That's why your code works, even though you are relying on the *increment expression* of the `for` loop to compensate for a rather contrived and meaningless decrease in `i`. That all seems rather crude to me, and having `i` as -1 which will happen if the first character is a dash will raise eyebrows during debugging.

It's probably best to use the `replace` method in `java.lang.String`. See [replace String with another in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216272/replace-string-with-another-in-java)

Else I'd prefer

```
for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.length(); /*intentionally empty*/){
    if (phoneNumber.charAt(i) == '-'){
        phoneNumber.deleteCharAt(i);
    } else {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

although this is still an O(N<sup>2</sup>) solution to an O(N) problem due to the repeated evaluation of `length()`! That can be solved by running the loop backwards, which will also reduce the number of element shuffles:

```
for (int i = -1 + phoneNumber.length(); i >= 0; /*intentionally empty*/){
    if (phoneNumber.charAt(i) == '-'){
        phoneNumber.deleteCharAt(i);
    } else {
        --i;
    }
}
```

Comment: "_Indeed this removes the dash from the phone number, but intuitively I would have expected it to remove the character just before the dash (because of the --)_ Lumbee " Seems your first statement answer OP question perfectly.

Comment: Since you've added your prefered solution, for this kind of code I prefer with `for(int i = phoneNumber.length() -1; i >= 0; --i) ...`

Comment: @AxelH: Yes that cuts down on the amount of shuffling.

Comment: You shoud always decrement here, if not might end up with an `OutOfBoundsException` and we already checked the character that will come in that position PS :I like the `-1` before the length, simple but much more readable