# parsing file & regex

Tags: java, regex, file, csv, parsing

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
"2014", "2", "AMC-South", "inpatient", "complication", "1", "2", "2", "13,125.83", "6,562.95"
```

How can I remove all the quotes and commas separating the items, so it can look like this?:

```
2014 2 AMC-South inpatient complication 1 2 2 13,125.83 6,562.95
```

I need this formatting so I can parse the csv file easier (using java). Thanks.

Comment: `String new_line = oldline.replace("\"", ");`  - btw. your expected result still has commas in it ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace String with another in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216272/replace-string-with-another-in-java)

Comment: @PatrickArtner i only need the commas separating the values to be gone. for example, 13,125.83 is a single number

Comment: Please take a peek at this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/24950812/7505395 - there are csv pasing lib recommendations in it.

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel.  I recommend the Apache CSV Parser.  Parsing CSV files is not something you should try to do yourself.  It's very easy to get this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Command line one-liner, using Perl:

```
$ echo '"2014", "2", "AMC-South", "inpatient", "complication", "1", "2", "2", "13,125.83", "6,562.95"'
"2014", "2", "AMC-South", "inpatient", "complication", "1", "2", "2", "13,125.83", "6,562.95"


$ echo '"2014", "2", "AMC-South", "inpatient", "complication", "1", "2", "2", "13,125.83", "6,562.95"' | perl -pe 's/^"//; s/", "/ /g; s/"$//;'
2014 2 AMC-South inpatient complication 1 2 2 13,125.83 6,562.95
```

Please note that this will only work correctly for CSV where the fields do not contain white space. That's the reason the CSV has those `"` around each field.

IMHO you should look for a Java CSV parser module. It will make life much easier in the long run.

Comment: Just showing the proper regexes which should work with any decent language or tool that uses PCRE.

Comment: OP is interested in a Java solution.  Regular expressions aside, this solution is completely useless to someone who doesn't know how PERL parses its command line.  It's also wrong in many cases - even if this were translated to a Java program, there are loads of CSV files on which it would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is algorithm outline:

> The java string replace() method returns a string replacing all the old char or CharSequence to new char or CharSequence.

```
String replaceString = your_string.replace("string_to_replace","[\",]+");
```

Consider this instead:

```
replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

**Possible Regex**

Answer (score 0):

A work around to avoid the CSV issue since multiple values contain commas, you could split around the following characters **", "**. Then all you need to do is remove the first and last **"** contained within those elements

```
String[] data = scanner.readLine().split("\", \"");

if(data.length() > 0 && data.length()  <= 10)
{
    data[0].replaceAll("\"", "");
    data[9].replaceAll("\"", "");
}
```

You could also split around **"[\D+],[\D+]"** and after the array is returned  remove any and all **"** from each string within the array.

Comment: yeah so why can't you split around ", " instead of only ,?? @PatrickArtner

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a library to parse data?
 Apache Commons CSV is great for that - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

```
File csvData = new File("/path/to/csv");
CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(csvData, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
for (CSVRecord record : parser) {
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: [`",?`](https://regex101.com/r/UR0vKo/1)

Details:

- `?` Matches between zero and one times

**Java code**:

```
String text = "\"2014\", \"2\", \"AMC-South\", \"inpatient\", \"complication\", \"1\", \"2\", \"2\", \"13,125.83\", \"6,562.95\"";
text = text.replaceAll("\",?", "");

System.out.println(text);
```

Output:

```
2014 2 AMC-South inpatient complication 1 2 2 13,125.83 6,562.95
```