# How to replace ',' to '\n' in String?

Tags: java

Well, the piece of code in my class :

```
  String sentence = "1. John," +
            "2. Mark," +
            "3. Sam";
```

And is logical that I have this output :

```
1. John
2. Mark
3. Sam
```

, so I need to replace all commas to line breaks ( \n ) ;

Comment: [`String::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,char)), http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace String with another in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216272/replace-string-with-another-in-java)

Please google before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I have missed something, this is as simple as using `replace` to change the command toa  newline character (`\n`):

```
String sentence = "1. John," +
                  "2. Mark," +
                  "3. Sam";
String newSentence = sentence.replace(",", "\n");
```

Depending upon environment, you may want to use a carriage-return\line-feed which would be `"\r\n"`.

Here's a [link](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replace) to a few examples of using it.

Answer (score 0):

You literally just replace , with \n:

```
String sentence = "1. John\n" +
        "2. Mark\n" +
        "3. Sam";
```

Comment: _uhhh_ I guess that has to be done through a code?