# Remove white space between 2 characters in java

Tags: java, string, whitespace

I have a requirement to extract some data from big string

I get input as **"Dial by :"** from server  and I need the input to be in format **"Dial by:"**

Input  : Dial by :

Output Expected : Dial by:

can someone help me how to remove space b/w "y" and ":"

Comment: Will the leading text always be `Dial by`?  Can you give more examples of how the replacement is supposed to happen?

Comment: String will be always starts with  "Dial by"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace String with another in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216272/replace-string-with-another-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to search for a optional whitespace followed by a `:` at the end of a `String` and replace it with a bare colon. Like,

```
String input = "Dial by :";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("\\s*:$", ":"));
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Only if they appear at the end of the `String`. That's the `$`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String#replaceAll` here:

```
String input = "Dial by :";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\bDial by\\s+:", "Dial by:");
System.out.println(input + "\n" + output);
```

This prints:

```
Dial by :
Dial by:
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string always starts with "Dial by", you could just do:

```
input = input.substring(0, 7) + input.substring(8);
```