# I am trying to code a find and replace Java program

Tags: java, string, replace, find

this is the loop im executing

```cs
for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    if (str[i]==strFind) {
        str[i]=strReplace;
        count++;
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the last word of the sentence has a period in some test cases and it doesn't have a period in some.And if i replace the word in the given manner. I cannot retain the period.
Is there a simpler solution for this?
Also, can replace all take a sting variable(strReplace-user input)?

Comment: Comparison is not really my issue here.Replacing while maintaining the punctuation marks given by the user is the problem with my code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace String with another in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216272/replace-string-with-another-in-java)

Comment: @AnubhavAgrawal `if (str[i]==strFind) {` quite sure the comparison is an issue

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of java's builtin String function, `replace` for your scenario.

```java
int getReplacementCount(String sentence,String searchWord, String replacement){      
   int count = 0;
   while(true){
      String replacedSentence = sentence.replace(searchWord,replacement);
      if(replacedSentence.equals(sentence){
         return count;
      else {
         count++;
         sentence = replacedSentence;
      }
   }
        
}
```

Comment: I used the string.replace directly and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue here is that you want to replace strings but you just watch and iterate over single characters of your string.
You could use [Apache Commons lang.](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lahttps://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.htmlng/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

```
StringUtils.replace(text, searchString, replacement)
```

Comment: Thank you I applied this and the code worked out fine.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a built in library in java.

You can simply use:

```
String str1 = "Hello world";

//usage: str1.replace(word_or_character to replace, replacement)
str1 = str1.replace(" ", "")
System.out.println(str1)
```

**Output:**

```
Helloworld
```